# Facebook Open Graph API and ShareDialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to share on facebook that user has played a game using my application. And I want to show with who he was playing (taggable friends). 
I have added a new Story "Play" with "Game Match" object. Action "Play" was generated automatically.
Right now I want to create a share dialog for user, so he can actually share it on facebook. Unfortunately my code doesn't work. However when I use the example url address of game match object it renders well and seems to work fine. What is going on? Could you please explain to me what the problem is? Here's my code. Please take a look at the 3 lines that are marked with comment "Way ##". When line Way #1 is uncommented everything works fine, but I want to use object that I've just created, so I'm trying to use way #2, but I get an error of "Failed to generate preview for user".

```
    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "games.match")
            .putString("og:title", "Quick Draw Round")
            .putString("og:image", "https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png")
            .putString("games:players", "499827376")
            .putInt("games:score", 100)
            .putString("og:determiner", "a")
            .putString("fb:app_id", "224658110883993")
            .build();

    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("queuedroid-test:play")
            .putString("match", "http://samples.ogp.me/413385652011237") // Way #1
//          .putObject("match", object)                                  // Way #2
            .build();

    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("match")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();
    ShareDialog dlg = new ShareDialog(activity);
    dlg.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: SUCCESS");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCancel: CANCEL");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onError: " + error.toString());
        }
    });
    dlg.show(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its the name Space that is not included.
The line `.putObject("match", object)` should be change to

```
.putObject("queuedroid-test:match", object)
```

Where queuedroid-test is your app name space on https://developers.facebook.com/apps